# jQuery css() unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/by7Ar/

I am making calls like `$('#divid').css('padding-left', '200px');` which should lengthen or shorten a particular div, because it has `{width: 100%}` as a style rule.  However, it doesn't do so until the browser window is resized or the element is redrawn (hidden then shown again).

I'm seeing this behavior in Chrome but not IE9 or Firefox.  Is this a Chrome bug?

(Comment out the last javascript line.  In Chrome, you can see that it is not behaving correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question, but is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/by7Ar/6/) what you're trying to achieve?